# Undefinded while evaluation Node with Drupal_add_js / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Jquery but not to JS, PHP, Drupal etc. And even new to stackoverflow.

For refreshing an webcam image i use for testing in a simple HTML file something like the following:

```
var URL = "http://webcam.tld/live.jpg";
var QueryString = "?random=RANDOM_NUMBER"; // simplified
$("#webcam").attr( "src", URL + QueryString ) ;
```

THIS WORKS!!!

In Drupal 7 the JS file is included with:

```
<?php
drupal_add_js( 'sites/site_1/themes/t1/js/webcams.js' , 'file' ); 
print '<img id="webcam" src="http://webcam.tld/live.jpg" />';
?>
```

The external JS file 'webcams.js' sounds like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
    var URL = "http://webcam.tld/live.jpg";
    var QueryString = "?random=RANDOM_NUMBER";
    // This gives TypeError (see below)
    $("#webcam").attr( "src" , URL + QueryString ); 
    // THIS WORKS 
    alert( "Hello" ); 
} ) ;
```

I'm getting the following error message:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#webcam")')

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your hints and your attention.
Hans

Comment: Are you forgetting to import the jQuery library itself? Or are you importing it but also calling `jQuery.noConflict()`?

Comment: I suggest that Drupal does it generally for my tiny script. The JS file above is (nearly) complete. The other libaries (Colorbox, Fancybox etc.) depend on jQuery. I also tried the "inline"-Mode of drupal_add_js but I've got "better" error messages with the file mode.

Comment: Well you could explicitly test to see whether `$` is null before trying to use it.  If it's null, then *something* is messing up jQuery.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed the $ var or space is NULL. Even when I use the inline mode of drupal_add_js with the code following far after loading the jquery library: `<script>jQuery(document).ready( function(){ if( $ ){  $("#webcam").css("border" , "10px green solid"); } else{ alert( "#webcam empty!" ); } } ) ;</script>`. Could be that I still not understand how to implement jQuery in Drupal.

Comment: Well if you're *not* getting the error when you use `jQuery` instead of `$`, you could try changing it to `jQuery("#webcam")`

Comment: Ufff! Thank you very much. I was sure I missed something tiny one but very important. I did know the identifier jQuery but even in the (expensive) Drupal developer book it is written different. A very bad start into jQuery but I hope with a better continuation. I wish you a very nice evening.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal7 you need to wrap your jQuery code into function, like this:

```
 // We define a function that takes one parameter named $.
(function ($) {
  // Here is our code
  // ...
}(jQuery));
```

Or, you can use full 'jQuery' instead of '$' everywhere.
You can read more on https://drupal.org/node/171213
Also, i suggest you to use Drupal behaviors (you you want follow drupal standarts)
http://blog.amazeelabs.com/en/comment/510193 - about drupal behaviors.